# Is there a way to embed a GPG public key in a script without adding it to the keyring?

Tags: shell-script, gpg

I have a script that basically needs to do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash 

GPG_PUBLIC_KEY=<<EOF
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.12 (GNU/Linux)
...
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
EOF

gpg --encrypt --with-public-key "$GPG_PUBLIC_KEY" myfile.txt
```

Is there a way to do this without importing the GPG key to the keyring first?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073288/decrypt-encrypted-gpg-file-using-external-secret-key , http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2004-October/023409.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to use the user's keyring at all, point GPG to a temporary keyring.

```
tmp=
trap 'rm -rf "$tmp"' EXIT INT TERM HUP
tmp=$(mktemp -d)
export GNUPGHOME="$tmp"
gpg --import <<EOF
…
EOF
gpg -e -r … myfile.txt
```

If you want to use the user's keyring as well, set `GNUPGHOME` only during the import command and pass `--keyring "$tmp/pubring.gpg"` to the second `gpg` command.